# Dynamic Data security trimming

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

When using dynamic data is there a way to only allow users to see records that contain their name/id #. Meaning that when they filter the data only their information shows up rather than every users.

Answer (score 1):

As to security implementing in Dynamic Data I would like to recommend you a great book **ASP.NET Dynamic Data Unleashed** by Oleg Sych.

As to your case, as i understood you need to display in **GridView** on *List.aspx* page only records that contain id or name of current logged user.

Let us consider the easiest way of solving your problem keeping Dynamic Data approach.

Let us assume, without taking into account of how the user get access to your Dynamic Data site, we have got user **Id** in code behind of *List.aspx*. For simplicity, assume that the our table contains user **Id**'s.

**List.aspx.cs** (partially)

```
public partial class List : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected int userId;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            userId = GetLoggedUser();  
        }        
    }
}
```

Then we should use special nonvisual control **QueryExtender** and using the TargetControlID property we associate it with our LINQ-based data source control (assume we have EntityDataSource in this case).

**List.aspx** (partially)

```
<asp:GridView 
    ID="gvTest" 
    runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="DetailsDataSourceTest"
    AllowPaging="true" 
    AllowSorting="false" 
    PageSize="10" 
    CssClass="gridview" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
    <asp:DynamicField DataField="UserId" />
    <asp:DynamicField DataField="Col1" />
    <asp:DynamicField DataField="Col2" />
    <asp:DynamicField DataField="Col3" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:EntityDataSource 
    ID="DetailsDataSourceTest" 
    runat="server"
    ConnectionString="name=TestEntities" 
    DefaultContainerName="TestEntities"
    EnableFlattening="false"
    EntitySetName="TableTestName" />
<asp:QueryExtender 
    ID="QueryExtenderTest" 
    runat="server"
    TargetControlID="DetailsDataSourceTest">
<asp:CustomExpression OnQuerying="QueryExtenderTest_Querying" />
</asp:QueryExtender>
```

As you can see we use **CustomExpression** option of **QueryExtender** control and then we  set its **OnQuerying** attribute to **QueryExtenderTest_Querying**. This will allow us to execute our **custom** LINQ query.

**List.aspx.cs** (partially)

```
protected void QueryExtenderTest_Querying(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.Expressions.CustomExpressionEventArgs e)
{
    if (/* check userId if you would like */)
    {
        e.Query = (from c in e.Query.Cast<TableTestName>()
                    where (c.UserId == userId)
                    select c);
    }
}
```

For more information:

[Walkthrough: Filtering Data in a Web Page Using Declarative Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537669.aspx)

**EDIT:**

Based on it simple solution and depending on implementing Routing in your Dynamic Data site you should use custom LINQ on Details.aspx page and Edit.aspx page in order to user could not access to not own record via query string.